# Team City build fails on dependency

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2013, nuget, teamcity

We have VS2013 hooked into SVN as our repository. We have Team City hooked into SVN. I am trying to create a build in Team City, but the build here keeps failing. The VS2013 project has a reference to another project and this is referenced via Nuget. On our local machine from within VS2013 the solution builds with no errors. When we check the source in to SVN, team City picks up that something has changed and then fails stating that it cannot find a reference to the file other project. The other project's source is stored in the same SVN repository and I thought that I might have to set this as an `artefact` to this project. However I seem to be having issues building the artefact command correctly. Can anyone point me to a good example of building the artefact command line, as I suspect it needs to build this first to be able to make a reference.

Comment: is TC checking out the entire source tree every time? Or just the subdirectory needed to build the current project?

Comment: @SamHolder Thanks for showing an interest in this question. I have now solved the issue. It appears that rather than setting it as an artefact as expected, in our case it had to be set as the first step and as a Nuget installer. This means that Nuget get's the artefect, builds it to a working directory then builds our project making a reference to the initial build....Strange way of doing things to my way of thinking, but that's how its been set up here.